# Collecting a value from JSON file with ember.js

Tags: json, ember.js

I am trying to pass a simple variable value into an HTML file using ember.js. My value is contained within a json file called value.json.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
 <h1>I won {{App.moneyvalue}} today!</h1>
```

However when I pass the json call via ember, it think that the entire call is a variable:

```
 App = Ember.Application.create({
   moneyvalue: function () {
     return $.getJSON( "js/value.json", function( data ) {
       return data.tot;
     });
   }
  }
```

And returns the following:

***I won function () { return $.getJSON( "js/donors.json", function( data ) { return data.tot; }); } today!***

As it seems to think that moneyvalue is a string variable as opposed to a value?

The jSON file is superbasic

```
{
  "tot": 100
}
```

Where is this going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you're supplying Handlebars with a function, generally you would use a computed or normal property on the object.  In this case you really just shouldn't define it in the application scope either, I'd recommend using an application route (it's the root route of your app).

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return $.getJSON( "js/value.json");
  }
});
```

Then in your handlebars just use

```
<h1>I won {{tot}} today!</h1>
```

Here's an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/576/edit

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, this seems to work but I still don't understand ember.js's logic so I will have a play with your example.

Comment: in simple terms, the model will be the scope of the application template (I explicitly named the template here, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/577/edit).

Comment: And is there a reason why when you add an additional function or code before or after model for example: `App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 
    placeholder: 'Enter your review',
 value : '10',
 classNames: ['amount'],
 
  model: function(){
    return $.getJSON( "js/value.json");
  }
});` The code stops working all together?